# Place a Count within an Ellipse

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am keeping track of a count of number of items. What I'd like to do is place this count in a nicely created circle (ellipse). Two questions; how to first do this, and how to ensure that regardless of whether the count is one or two digits the number remain exactly in the center of the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place both items in the grid with the proper Vertical/Horizontal alignment.

This way you can scale the grid and the ellipse will scale as well.  And if you are really "clever" you can even set the min and max values of the ellipse so it looks like a "loading bar".

```XAML
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Ellipse Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="10"/>
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="100000" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

---

[image]